# PHP preg_match is not working properly

Tags: php, preg-match

My client ask me to add new a rule to the username to his website login. Therefore I've tried the following code.

```
  $userid = "12345678SM"; //format of the username
  $check="/^[0-9]+[S].[M]{10}$/i";
  $check2="/^[0-9]+[F].[M]{10}$/i";
    print($name);
  if(!preg_match($check,$userid) || !preg_match($check2,$userid)) {
    print('The user id is invalid');                    
  }
```

However, even though I entered the correct format of the username it's printing the error. I've actually used this code sometimes ago and worked but here I don't understand why it's not working. Could anyone please help me out of this ?

FYI: Format of the username should be 7 digits and 2 selected alphabet characters eg: SM or FM

Comment: Your userid example code says 8 digits and your FYI says 7.

Answer (score 3):

`[M]{10}` means that 10 M is required.

The correct check would be:

```
$check="/^\d{7}[SF]M$/i";
if (!preg_match($check, $userid)) {
    print('The user id is invalid');                    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "`[M]{10}`" part matches "MMMMMMMMMM".
The format you described could be checked with

```
^[0-9]{8}[S|F]M$
```

Also you said

> $userid = "12345678SM"; (**8 digits**)

but

> Format of the username should be **7 digits** and 2 selected alphabet characters

My example will work for 8.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply your updates works fine but could you please tell me is there way to ignore alphabet uppercase and lowercase check ignore ?